# WIQL The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priorty]».'

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, wiql

below is my Query and i am getting the Error:
**query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priorty]».'**

```
string querystring = string.Format("select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType]," +
                " [System.Title],[System.State],[System.AssignedTo]," +
                "[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints]," +
                "[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority],[System.IterationPath]" +
                " FROM WorkItemLinks" +
                " WHERE" +
                " ([Source].[System.TeamProject]='{0}'" +
                " and [Source].[System.IterationPath]='MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Pluse Pheonix\\Sprint 1'" +
                " and (Source.[System.WorkitemType]='User Story' " +
                " or [Source].[System.WorkitemType]='Task'))" +
                " and [System.Links.LinkType]='System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'" +
                " and [Target].[System.WorkItemType] <> '' " +
                " ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank]," +
                " [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priorty]" +
                " mode (Recursive)", projectname);



          Query treequery = new Query(workItemStore, querystring);
          WorkItemLinkInfo[] links = treequery.RunLinkQuery();
```

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: yes @starianchen-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priorty]` to `[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority]` in ORDER By statement.